# Robocopy files to different destinations - per file

Tags: robocopy

I'm trying to mirror a direcory with images to a set of detination folders, where each folder receives only a part of the source directory.

Example
say the source contains 10 images:
1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg, 6.jpg, 7.jpg, 8.jpg, 9.jpg, 10.jpg

These would be mirrored to 4 destination folders in a slicewise pattern:

folder1: 1.jpg, 5.jpg, 9.jpg

folder2: 2.jpg, 6.jpg, 10.jpg

folder3 3.jpg, 7.jpg

folder4: 4.jpg, 8.jpg

How would I write such a pattern for robocopy?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> How would I write such a pattern for robocopy?

You wouldn't.  You would write a script that passes every fourth file to a different robocopy instance with an appropriate folder target.  How, *precisely*, you'd do that would depend on the scripting language you're using, which you haven't said, but you should be able to find a solution search for "every nth item" or something similar.